# Differences between onward, forth, ahead, front, fore, forward

Tags: meaning

When shall I use each one of them?
It's really confusing.
When I translate them they all mean practically the same.

Could you give some examples and when to use and when not to?

Comment: ? I said translate

Comment: Actually, you said *traduce* -- Glorfindel changed it to *translate*.

Comment: If you examine the edit history (click on 'edited 2 days ago') you will see that the exact text of your original post was *When shall i use each one of them Its really confusing When i traduce them they all means practically the same

Could you give some examples and when to use and when not to*

Answer (score 3):

*Onward* - Continuing in a direction.

> They stopped for a rest, and then continued to walk onward.

*Forth* - Moving away from a location

> They got onto their ship and sailed forth in search of gold.

*ahead* - Something which is in the direction you are travelling, such that if you keep going you will eventually arrive at its location.

> They were racing him, but he was ahead of them by 2 miles.

*front* - The part of an object which should be pointed forwards, e.g. the opposite of 'back' or 'rear'.

> The box said 'open me' on the front.

*in front* - Positioned by the front.

> He parked his car in front of the house.

*fore* - Similar to front

*forward* - Travelling so that the front is pointing in the direction of travel.

> The car drove forward

*forward* - The same as in front

> He was further forward in the race.

Comment: Your definition of _ahead_ strikes me as odd. Couldn't something be "ahead" that _is_ the destination, or even past the destination, as long as it is in the direction you are moving?

Comment: You're right I will edit

Comment: Also possibly worth noting that while "fore" is similar in usage to "front" it is also a bit archaic/literary.

Answer (score 1):

They differ in meaning, and in register.

The simplest words in your list are ahead, front and forward.

Forward usually indicates a motion: "Move forward"

Front is a side of something, It doesn't usually indicate a motion: "The front of the house"

Ahead means "to the front of". You can say "move ahead of me" to mean "overtake"

As with many common words, there is overlap, and secondary meanings, a dictionary can list these.

Fore, forth and onward are more limited in use, and are mostly poetical or marked, appearing in various idioms "Go forth and multiply", "Onward and upward". Or in golf, to warn other players: "Fore!"